# Compare two columns in each of 200,000 rows in an Excel document with Python

Tags: python, excel

**I am trying to compare the following data:**

```
|text_col|corr_acc|
+--------+--------+
|Car123  |xxx1    |
|Car234  |xxx2    |
|Car123  |xxx1    |
|Car456  |xxx3    |
|Car234  |xxx2    |
|Car123  |xxx5    |
```

- If `text_col` in first row (`Car123`) can be found in any of the other rows (for example in row 3) then `corr_acc` must be compared.
- If `corr_acc` for each row is the same then this must be written to a new list called match.
- If not then both values of `corr_acc` must be added to a list called no_match with the original value.

The end results for the no_match list would look something like this:

```
|text_col |corr_acc|Result   |
+---------+--------+---------+
|Car123   |xxx1    |xxx1,xxx5|
|Car234   |xxx2    |         |
|Car123   |xxx1    |xxx1,xxx5|
|Car456   |xxx3    |         |
|Car234   |xxx2    |         |
|Car123   |xxx5    |xxx1,xxx5|
```

**I have the following code that worked for me but is too slow** (need to compare 200 000 rows):

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\\peter\\Book3.xlsx')
sheet = wb['2018']
i = 0
j = 0
list_match = []
list_no_match = []

for i in range(2,(len(sheet['A']))+1):
    text_col_c_1 = str((sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value))
    corr_acc_1 = str((sheet.cell(row=i, column=11).value))
    for j in range(2+i,(len(sheet['A']))+1):
        text_col_c_2 = str((sheet.cell(row=j, column=3).value))
        corr_acc_2 = str((sheet.cell(row=j, column=11).value))
        if text_col_c_1 is text_col_c_2:
            if corr_acc_1 is corr_acc_2:

                list_match.append(text_col_c_1+","+corr_acc_1+","+corr_acc_2+"\n")
            else:
               list_no_match.append(text_col_c_1+","+corr_acc_1+","+corr_acc_2+"\n")
        else:
            #list_no_match.append(text_col_c_1+","+corr_acc_1+"\n")
            pass


F = open("d:\\peter\\match_list.txt", "w")
for each in  list_match:
   F.write(each)
F.close()

F = open("d:\\peter\\no_match_list.txt", "w")
for each in  list_no_match:
   F.write(each)
F.close()
```

**How can I improve the speed of my code?**

Comment: maybe it is worth to read both columns into tuples and store them in one array? and then loop throw array and compare members of each tuple?